# mysql error : check MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please check the issue in this line.
I understand if the question looks naive, i'll close it myself if there its not contributing enough.

```
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '20','none',now())' at line 2
```

Code :

```
$query_cs_pm = mysql_query("INSERT INTO coating_station_pm (challan_no_cs_pm,emp_inch_cs_pm,shift_time,client_name,diameter_cs_pm,no_of_bars_cs_pm,tempreture_cs_pm,remarks_cs_pm,datetime) 
                                              VALUES ('".$challan_no."','".$emp_inch_id."','".$shift_time_cs_pm."','".$client_name_cs_pm."','".$bar_dia_cs_pm[$i]."','".$no_of_bars_cs_pm[$i].",'".$tempreture_cs_pm[$i]."','".$remarks_cs_pm[$i]."',now())"
                                  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `'".$no_of_bars_cs_pm[$i].",` is a `'` missing at the end of the Parameter.

You should use prepared Statement so this can not be a Problem.